# extrinsics from same account result in underutilized blockspace

Tags: extrinsic, transaction-pool, mempool, tx-pool

I'm sending multiple extrinsics from the same account. The nonce is increased before a new extrinsic is sent, and all extrinsics are sent as immortal.

My goal is to fill the blocks as much as possible, but on average there's only one extrinsic being included per block (while their weight consumption is quite small).

Meanwhile, there's plenty extrinsics sitting in the pool. All extrinsics in the pool are from this same account, so there's no competing extrinsics.

Why is that?

Does the fact that all extrinsics are coming from the same account make the collator de-prioritize them?